# How do I register a python function to be called when garbage collection (GC) starts and is completed?

Tags: python, pyspark

We have a complex Python/Spark program that uses a lot of memory. We would like to be notified when Python and Java start a garbage collection. The python `gc` module documentation discusses callbacks and says what arguments they are provided with, but it does not say how to register a python function as a callback to be called when python starts and completes garbage collection.

How do I register a python function to be called when garbage collection (GC) starts and is completed?

Comment: I am curious to know what is this and how can we leverage that in Pyspark. would you like to share your findings in some more details. I am using spark and learning it and this is something new to me. Thanks

Comment: Hi, @vikrantrana.Our usage of Spark is non-standard. We have an RDD with approximately 11M rows, where each row consists of a Python dictionary that is between 1MB and 100MB in size. The large object in the dictionary is a numpy array. We are running out of memory, but behavior changes depending on how and when GC is invoked. So we're trying to get visibility into the process.

Comment: Thanks for the information shared. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just append your function to the `callbacks` list

```
import gc

def gb_callback_example(phase, info):
   ... Do some stuff

gc.callbacks.append(gb_callback_example)
```

> gc.callbacks A list of callbacks that will be invoked by the garbage
>   collector before and after collection. The callbacks will be called
>   with two arguments, phase and info.
>
> phase can be one of two values:
>
> “start”: The garbage collection is about to start.
>
> “stop”: The garbage collection has finished.
>
> info is a dict providing more information for the callback. The following keys are currently defined:
>
> “generation”: The oldest generation being collected.
>
> “collected”: When phase is “stop”, the number of objects successfully collected.
>
> “uncollectable”: When phase is “stop”, the number of objects that could not be collected and were put in garbage.
>
> Applications can add their own callbacks to this list. The primary use
>   cases are:
>
> Gathering statistics about garbage collection, such as how often various generations are collected, and how long the collection takes.
>
> Allowing applications to identify and clear their own uncollectable types when they appear in garbage.

Comment: Thanks. That is completely non-obvious.